CloudKit Private Database Record Zone Limit
I am following this document from Apple to implement sharing with CloudKit.  In it, Apple says

NSPersistentCloudKitContainer uses CloudKit zone sharing to share objects. Each share has its own record zone on the CloudKit server. CloudKit has a limit on how many record zones a database can have.

What is the record zone limit for a private CloudKit database?
I can find information about record and participant limits but not on record zone limits.

I can't find any info on any such limit. There's no error code specific to reaching a record zone count limit that I see. FWIW - I have a private database with 16 zones so I know it supports at least that many.

You can create max 1000 custom record zones in a private CloudKit database.
When you exceed this limit, you will receive a server message "Custom Zone limit exceeded".
This limit is active since 2016, before that you could create an unlimited number of record zones.
